# Configure and connect fence device through proxy server?

Tags: cluster, high-availability, pacemaker, http-proxy, fencing

I'm setting up a cluster with [Pacemaker and Corosync (from Clusterlabs)](https://clusterlabs.org/pacemaker/doc/2.1/Clusters_from_Scratch/singlehtml/index.html#document-fencing).
It works fine but i need to configure the fencing.

Servers run on a VMWare ESXi infrastructure. 
I have a frontend server (with an public IP address) configured with Nginx as a reverse proxy. And 2 backend nodes on a private network. 
The 2 nodes are connected to the internet via a proxy server (Squid) to access the web.

I tried a connection with *fence_vmware_soap* but it doesn't work through the proxy server (by setting http_proxy variables).
I don't know how to configure fencing ? Maybe with an other agent ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find answer about proxy.

Just redirect traffic by using the proxy server as gateway.
Solution used here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-configuring_nat_using_nftables#sec-Configuring_source_NAT_using_nftables

```bash
nft add table MY_RULE
nft -- add chain MY_RULE prerouting { type nat hook prerouting priority -100 \; }
nft add chain MY_RULE postrouting { type nat hook postrouting priority 100 \; }

nft add rule MY_RULE postrouting oifname "ens192" snat to ip_public_server_proxy

echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" > /etc/sysctl.d/95-IPv4-forwarding.conf
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.d/95-IPv4-forwarding.conf
```